# ImageButton no background but turn blue when touched

Tags: java, android

I've added an ImageButton(an image of a round gray X,transparent background) .It gets dynamically added to a layout.

```
final ImageButton btnx = new ImageButton(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            50, 50);
    layoutParams.setMargins(14, 14, 14, 14);
    l5.addView(btnx, layoutParams);
    btnx.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonx);
```

The problem here is that under it,there's a gray button.I know how i can hide it(make it transparent or set my image as the background) but then it won't have that nice effect of turning light blue when clicked.
How can i make it so that it still has this effect but the gray button doesn't show on the background? 
Or is there any other way to make a button out of my gray X with transparent background and make it turn light blue(as the usual buttons do) when touched and get back to normal color when not touched/clicked ?

Also : does anyone know the standard size of an EditText.I need to align those X's to some EditTexts that are on the same row but on different layouts and i can't do that without knowing the exact size of the editTexts..if the size of the X is smaller or bigger it will start to be unaligned when i add like 100 rows dynamically.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You should use selector for button states:

```
final ImageButton btnx = new ImageButton(this);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            50, 50);
    layoutParams.setMargins(14, 14, 14, 14);
    l5.addView(btnx, layoutParams);
    btnx.setImageResource(R.drawable.buttonx);
```

Also, add buttonx.xml into drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/buttonx_pressed"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/buttonx_normal"/>

</selector>
```

And put your images with normal and pressed states ("buttonx_pressed" and "buttonx_normal") into drawable folder too.

Answer (score 0):

Image button is a combination of two views, ImageView and Button by default.

When you touch an ImageButton, ImageView remains static but the default Button view changes its state.
 So either set background of the ImageButton as null and set and image resource as the "src" of the imageButton or use background selector.

Also if you want that Image button should not turn blue but should give pressed effect, for that you need have some images of the image button size 
 - one complete transparent for the normal state
 - one transparent from center but tranlucent from borders for clicked effect.

Then set the actual image as the background and make a selector with these frame images and set it as the src of the ImageButton.

For the edit text, take a screen capture of your mobile screen and measure it.